# Compile error: virtual memory exhausted

Tags: c++, memory, swap, ram

I am trying to compile an application but I seem to be running into a preset memory constraint. When compiling, it gives me the following error:
"virtual memory exhausted: Nicht genügend Hauptspeicher verfügbar", so I read this as having not enough RAM+Swap available.

As I am compiling this on a machine with 32GB RAM, this is quite unlikely. I checked the memory consumption and it breaks down at 3GB. Compiling the application on a different machine works, it needs around 3.5GB. I'm running on fedora 19, 64bit.

I also checked the available user memory using ulimit -a, but everything is set to unlimited (max memory size, virtual memory).

Are there any other places where there might be a limit set to the maximum memory available to a process or user? I'm starting to run out of options.

Comment: `Nicht genügend Hauptspeicher verfügbar` I didn't know you get error messages  in other languages a well :)

Comment: You tell us what operating system you use and how many RAM you have. But what compiler are you using?

Comment: And which options are you passing it?

Comment: might be a wild shot, but since it breaks down at 3GiB... could it be that You are running a x86 version of the compiler and simply runs out of the virtual memory as it hits 32-bit addressing limitations?

Comment: Have you tried changing the size of your swap file?

Comment: I'm compiling with MPICH, and checked for 64-bit version. I played around with the flags, and now it is getting interesting. With -g it breaks down at 3GB, with -O2 it breaks the 3GB limit and compiles... Any reasons as to why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

If the *compiler* is running out of memory, it might be due to a compiler bug, or some messed up template expansion (remember that in C++ templates are Turing complete, I remember some <strike>demented</strike> creative soul did something like computing $\pi$ to a lot of digits *at compile time*). Check your templates.

In case of possible compiler bug, upgrade everything. Try using `clang++` instead of  `g++`. Play with optimization and other settings.

Where does the code come from? Has somebody else built it?